# How to pass the querystring parameter into FormControl in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, query-string, formview

I am passing a value from one form to the other. The second form in inserting the data field into the table. How do I pass the ID(strPID) passed from the first form into the form control PatronIDTextBox of the second form?

VB.Code: on Page load -- strPID = Request.QueryString("value1")

Form control:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    PatronID:
   <asp:TextBox ID="PatronIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PatronID") %>' />
```

Thanks

---

Ok, Now I am trying to say it this way in object datasource so I can send it into insert statement without being displayed on the screen.

```
<Insert Parameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PatronID" Type="int32" QueryStringField="value1" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PatronName" Type="String" QueryStringField="value2" />
</InsertParameter>
```

InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblIncident] ([PatronID], [PatronName]) values (@PatronID, @PatronName)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly putting the value into the textbox?  Like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PatronIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%= Request.QueryString("Value1") %>' />
```

Just be careful, because this approach could allow a XSS attack.  You might want to read-up on those.

Comment: No I did not. Then I thought I can directly enter into the insert statement as a querystring parameter but that is not working either.

Comment: Oh.  You changed the original question.  I'll have to update my answer to address your second question now.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the text box for both id and name and instead I modified the objectdatasource Insert statement as follows. The value of value1 and value2 is captured on page load event.

```
<InsertParameters>
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PatronID" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="value1" />
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PatronName" Type="String" QueryStringField="value2"/>
</InsertParameters>
```